# How to save remote notification count in android shared preferences

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

Am trying to record total count of remote notification which I received for later use.

I have a notification class to push notification

```
public class PushNotificationHandler {
    private Context _this
     public PushNotificationHandler(Context context){
        this._this = context;
    }
    public void send(String title, String message, Bitmap image) {
        //......
        //......
        notificationManager.notify(Utils.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

        //Get old count
        int count = AppController.getInstance(_this).getCount() + 1;

        //Then try saving new count
        AppController.getInstance(_this).setCount(count);
    }
}
```

I also tried in `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class PushMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private int notification_count = 0;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        PushNotificationHandler notify = new PushNotificationHandler(getApplicationContext());

        if (!Utils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            notify.broadcast(remoteMessage);
        }else {
            notification_count++;
            notify.send("title", "message", null);
           AppController.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setCount(notification_count);

        }
    }
}
```

None of the above worked

My shared preference class

```
public class AppController {
    private static AppController instance;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static Context appcontext;


    private AppController(Context context) {
        appcontext = context;

    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppController(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        if (sharedPreferences == null)
            sharedPreferences = appcontext.getSharedPreferences("InitializeAppCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
        editor.putInt("NotificationCount", count);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return getSharedPreferences().getInt("NotificationCount", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add getSharedPreferences() method ?

Comment: These should work , how/where do you test whether its working or not ?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim On real device

Comment: I meant the code that you used

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim I tried `AppController.getInstance(_this).getCount()` in `onResume()` it always show `0`. But my notification is working properly.